# Why does current not flow from a higher potential in the primary circuit to a lower potential in the secondary circuit of potentiometer?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image: Image showing a potentiometer being used to determine a battery's emf]

#1 Why does no current flow when the potential drop across P is equal to the emf of the battery in the secondary circuit(the lower part of the circuit)?

#2 Why does current not flow from 9V to 3V of the battery in the secondary circuit? [As current flows from higher to lower potential]

Comment: You've labeled the negative end of the 3V battery as 0V. That's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Current will only flow through the galvanometer if there is a potential drop across it. When the system is balanced then the voltage on the top side is 3V and the voltage on the bottom side is also 3V. The voulage difference is, therefore 0V so no current will flow.